# In git, why is a local branch required to create a remote branch?

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand why I am unable to **create** a remote branch with a valid reference such as `head^` or a SHA.

```
git push origin SHA:test
git push origin head^:test
```

Both of these commands fail with:

```
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: test
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'remote'
```

This forces me to create and immediately delete a local branch, which seems silly

```
git branch tmp head^
git push origin tmp:test
git branch -D tmp
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

---

Note that the first two commands are successful if `origin/test` already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git push origin SHA:refs/heads/test
```

will create the `test` branch on the origin remote.  (You can also specify remotes by URL or pathname if as here you don't need defaults).

Branch refs are refs that start `refs/heads`. Tag refs are refs that start `refs/tags`.  Remote-tracking refs start `refs/remotes/remote`.  So when you say `git push origin SHA:test`, with no example to work from git would have to just plain guess.